Is there an exact equivalent shortcut in Kubuntu to Windows' WIN+D?
Super/Command/Win + D in Kubuntu immediately takes you to the desktop, but it seems to do it slightly differently than Windows.
In windows, the shortcut will minimize every window and result in you being at the desktop. In Kubuntu, it seems to just take you to the desktop. so, opening any window (new or existing) after Super+D in Kubuntu will re-open all of the windows and put them back in their prior position/size.
I find Windows' Win+D to be useful to get to desktop and then re-open one window only in a tiled size and have access to the desktop (example: having an image editor open and a browser. finding a picture online on my browser, downloading it (to desktop), and then quickly WIN+D-ing, re-opening the image editor and dragging and dropping the downloaded image into the image editor). If you do this in Kubuntu, any other application will need to be minimized again once you re-open the image editor.
Is there any shortcut in Kubuntu that will do this, or can a setting be changed to actually minimize all windows when getting to the desktop?
